# Emacs - Specific Bracket Behavior Customization

Tags: emacs, elisp

In emacs, I prefer the electric-pair-mode behavior for parentheses and brackets as opposed to what seems like the "jumpy" default behavior.

However, I currently use auto-newline and like the automatic newlines inserted with the curly brackets (I use BSD style indentation).

What I would like to figure out is how to best combine these behaviors, so that when I type an opening curly bracket, an indented line and closing bracket will follow.

I tried looking on Google for potential solutions, but I had trouble trying to phrase what exactly I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find an easy way to do what you want, though eventually [`electric-layout-mode`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Misc-for-Programs.html) might help. So I offer the following hack:

```
(defun c-open-brace ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((electric-pair-mode nil))
    (c-electric-brace nil)
    (save-excursion (newline) (insert ?}) (indent-according-to-mode))))

(define-key c-mode-map (kbd "{") 'c-open-brace)
```